# Hanging 60 lb beveled glass frame in courtyard on a brick wall

Tags: mounting

The mirror had a frame on it but it rotted off from being outside. I would like to hang the mirror now but need help to know what I need to purchase to hang it. I have a heavy chain that I had connected to the frame previously to hang it on the wall. I could use the chain again it I could figure out what to put on the mirror to hang it from. Thank you.

Comment: Is the brick in sound condition? Would you prefer one large hole or several small ones?

Comment: Yes, it is a sound wall.

Comment: probably several small ones. Would the big hole be noticeable if the mirror was removed?

Comment: Sure, if you didn't patch it. So would the small ones.

Comment: then either is fine

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Z clips, unless you want the chain as ornamental.[image]

These are attached to the wall and to the mirror's new frame.

To attach to the wall, I'd set anchors into the mortar (It's as strong as the brick and easier to patch if you move the mirror later.) Then use screws to attach the clips.

You have some fussy alignment to do to get the clips to match when using more than 2 pairs.

If you don't want to put a frame on the mirror, look at buying a single sheet of pressure treated plywood, cut it to match the size of the mirror, and glue to mirror to the plywood.  I don't recommend this for an exterior application.  Glass has a fairly high coefficient of thermal expansion.  I think the usual is to leave 1/8" per foot of glass dimension.  So a 4 foot high window has 1/2" of header space in the frame for it to wiggle in.  Might be 1/16" per foot.  Have to look.

A compromise is to use a plywood back, and then a lighter weight frame.  Frame elements only need to be big enough to hide the expansion room.  If you go this route, be sure to put drain holes in the channel at the bottom.  Otherwise water getting into that channel will rot the wood.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. With the z clips, would they just attach to the mirror because you could not put holes in the mirror. Can I get those z clips at Lowes or Home Depot?

Answer (score 0):

Mirror brackets are ideal for attaching bare glass mirrors to walls

Comment: Hi, Jansen. Would you expand this a bit (at least with punctuation)? Perhaps a picture?

Comment: yes please do expand a bit with tool or items purchased and picture if possible.